# Use the variables in erb file from sh script file

Tags: ruby, bash, sh, erb

I have a script name **first.sh** and in that I have called few variables like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

index1_0="a_b_c"
index2_0="b_c_d"
index3_0="c_d_e"
```

The script path of **first.sh** is **goal/first.sh**.I'm trying to use above variables called in first.sh in another **second.erb** file like below:

```
% H = Hash["a" => "@index1_0",
%   "b" => "@index2_0",
%   "d" => "@index3_0",]
```

I need to use the variables declared in **first.sh** script file in **second.erb** file but not getting the exact output. Can someone help here?

Comment: What do you mean by `but not getting the exact output`? Do you mean "avoid execution of the script"?

Comment: @BroiSatse I need the .erb syntax for calling the variables used in **first.sh** script

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<%= ENV['index1_0'] %>
```

to access the value of an environment variable that you need to export from `first.sh` like

```
export index1_0="a_b_c"
```

and source it

```
source first.sh
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what I need to modify in first.sh script and second.erb files....I need to use the variables from .sh script file to .erb file...

Comment: The script file is in a different location and .erb file is in a different location....can you please tell me how to read the variables in .erb file which are declared in the script file.

Comment: the location of the script doesn't matter as you are sharing the variables through a common *environment*